# Flutter how to scrape an image source element on a website

Tags: android, flutter, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse an img src that is featured on a website and include it into my app. I'm using the flutter package [Web Scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper), this is the code I've tried so far:

```
final webScraper = WebScraper('https://tiktok.com');
if(await webScraper.loadWebPage('/@$enteredUsername')){
  tiktokProfilePictureURL = webScraper.getElement('img', ['src']);
  print(tiktokProfilePictureURL);
}
```

The image I'm trying to get the URL from is the profile picture of the account, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

When I look into the code of the website it provides the link to the website image but when I try to parse this in web scraper it can't seem to find it.

[image]

This is the WebScraper output:
[image]

As you can see it finds various .svg images but not the .jpeg profile picture I'm trying to find.

Or maybe there is another way to parse this image src url? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution ?